# setInterval for each row, time is coming from backend. - Jquery

Tags: jquery

How to setInterval for each row, time is coming from backend JSON. from that time need add time for every second?

```
var el = $('#feedback_tasks_list tbody');
el.empty();
for(var i = 0 ; i < timeList.length ; i++)
{
    var tableRow = $('<tr class = "time_row" data-TIME-id="'+ timeList[i].id+'"></tr>');
    tableRow.appendTo(el);
    $('<td></td>').html(timeList[i].customerName).appendTo(tableRow);
    $('<td></td>').html(secToMin(timeList[i].fromTime)).appendTo(tableRow);
}

// Seconds to minutes or hour
var secToMin = function(seconds){
    var sec = parseInt(seconds);
    if(sec < 60){
        if(sec < 10)
        {
            sec = '0'+sec;
        }
        return('00:00:'+sec);
    }
    else if(sec >= 60 && sec < 3600){
        var min = parseInt(sec/60);
        if(min < 10)
        {
            min = '0'+min;
        }
        var remainingSec =  parseInt(sec%60);
        if(remainingSec < 10)
        {
            remainingSec = '0'+remainingSec;
        }
        return('00:'+min+':'+remainingSec);
    }
    else{
        var hour = parseInt(sec/3600);
        if(hour < 10)
        {
            hour = '0'+hour;
        }
        var remainingHour = parseInt(sec%3600);
        var min = parseInt(remainingHour/60);
        if(min < 10)
        {
            min = '0'+min;
        }
        var remainingSec =  parseInt(remainingHour%60);
        if(remainingSec < 10)
        {
            remainingSec = '0'+remainingSec;
        }
        return(hour+':'+min+':'+remainingSec);

    }
}
```

If i get 150 sec from backend secToMin(timeList[i].fromTime) am showing 00:02:30.
after that i need to add a second for every second. for that how to use setIntrval, and from where i call that function.
pls help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array/object that will hold only actual time values for each row (let's call it `times`), and then loop through all of them in the setInterval callback, incrementing them and recalculating the value for each row.

Here's a simple example:

```js
var times = [123, 431, 1];                   // simulating times data
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div'); // get all the elements
setInterval(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {    // loop through them
    // increment each, recalculate and modify HTML
    divs[i].textContent = secToMin(++times[i]);
  }
}, 1000);

// Seconds to minutes or hour
var secToMin = function(seconds){
    var sec = parseInt(seconds);
    if(sec < 60){
        if(sec < 10)
        {
            sec = '0'+sec;
        }
        return('00:00:'+sec);
    }
    else if(sec >= 60 && sec < 3600){
        var min = parseInt(sec/60);
        if(min < 10)
        {
            min = '0'+min;
        }
        var remainingSec =  parseInt(sec%60);
        if(remainingSec < 10)
        {
            remainingSec = '0'+remainingSec;
        }
        return('00:'+min+':'+remainingSec);
    }
    else{
        var hour = parseInt(sec/3600);
        if(hour < 10)
        {
            hour = '0'+hour;
        }
        var remainingHour = parseInt(sec%3600);
        var min = parseInt(remainingHour/60);
        if(min < 10)
        {
            min = '0'+min;
        }
        var remainingSec =  parseInt(remainingHour%60);
        if(remainingSec < 10)
        {
            remainingSec = '0'+remainingSec;
        }
        return(hour+':'+min+':'+remainingSec);

    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

---

So in your case, you could add a class to those cells that hold time (just to make selecting easier):

```
$('<td class="timeHolder"></td>').html(secToMin(timeList[i].fromTime)).appendTo(tableRow);
```

and then in the setInterval callback, you'd do the same I did in my example above:

```
var $timeHolders = $('.timeHolder');

setInterval(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < $timeHolders.length; i++) {
    $timeHolders.eq(i).html(secToMin(++timeList[i].fromTime));
  }
}, 1000);
```